# I upgraded NHibernate and now I get MSDTC issues when I'm not interested in using MSDTC

Tags: nhibernate, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

I upgraded my NHibernate libraries as well as Castle.Windsor.
I also moved from using NHibernateIntegration to Castle.Facilities.NHibernate

I implemented the advice at NHFacilities page here - https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki

Now when I run my web app, I am stopped by various MSDTC exceptions - the latest being **Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction**

I have to say at this point, I had to look up what MSDTC was, and can confirm that I have no interest in using it whatsoever! ;-)

I didn't configure it, nor can I see any place where I was made aware that I would be using it.

Any googling I do, concerns people who know that they're using it and why.
Whereas, I have no idea what just happened.

Can anyone tell me what it might be about either the new NHibernate (3.2) or the NHFacilities or Castle.Windsor related dependencies that causes my code to start using MSDTC?

And can I remove it?

Or is there something more sinister that is truly wrong with my code that I need to fix? Keeping in mind, it worked, as is, before the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

as the description of [NHFacilities](https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki) implied:

> The NHibernate facility slots into NHibernate and Castle AutoTx
>   facility for LTM-transactions perfectly

and [Castle AutoTx](https://github.com/haf/Castle.Transactions) is responsible for managing the transactions, I'm not familiar with these components but I guess the Castle AutoTx is somehow escalating the transactions to MSDTC, so if you didn't mean to use MSDTC, you should consult the Castle AutoTx documentation for configuration.